# file create error in php

Tags: php, file, file-permissions

I'm  creating the file using the php function but it is not working.I have created the folder and set its permission 0777 but it is not creating the file.

I'm using the following code. plz let me know what is going wrong.

```
   $cachefile ='/cache/cache.text';
   $file=chmod($cachefile, 777);
   if (file_exists($file)) {
    include($file); 
    } else{
   $fp = fopen('/cache/cache.txt', 'w');    
   fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
   fclose($fp);
    ob_end_flush();
```

for  ob_get_contents() function I'm using the ob_start () function. If I create the file manually it is working and showing the buffering data.Plz let me know how can I create the file using the fopen function.

Comment: Looks like you're setting the permission to `.text` instead of `.txt`, so they are not the same file.  Let us know what the error is as well.

Comment: Replace `$fp = fopen('/cache/cache.txt', 'w');` with `$fp=fopen('/cache/cache.txt', 'w')or die("can't open file"); ` to help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This line has several issues:

```
$file=chmod($cachefile, 777);
```

1. At that time, the file may not exist, so it may show an error (you cannot do chmod on a file that does not exist).
2. [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) will return either `true` or `false`. You are trying to use this return value in your code later, saved in the `$file` variable.

This should work if the `cache` folder is writable:

```
   $cachefile ='cache/cache.txt';
   if (file_exists($cachefile)) {
       include($cachefile); 
   } 
   else {
       $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');    
       fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
       fclose($fp);
       ob_end_flush();
   }
```